# How to get weights into text file from saved model in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a trained model in 'h5' format. It has some layers and their names with it. I want to read the weights and put them in a single array text file.
I am trying to use h5py but it needs the name of layer in details manually and then weights can be extracted and saved.
Is there other technique to write the weights to text file automatically?